# Querying previous year in FME?

Tags: fme-form

I have a field that posts CURYEAR but I am trying to write an FME Attributesetter that would post the CURYEAR minus 1. So technically the year prior to the captured date. Does anyone know how to scrip that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally clear about the scenario.

If you have an attribute containing a year (say 2011) and you want minus 1 (2010) then use the arithmetic editor window (inside an AttributeCreator or ExpressionEvaluator transformer) and set up @Value(CURYEAR)-1

If you want to create a date that is one before the current year (i.e the year before the year you are running the workspace) then do this:

Use an AttributeCreator and create an attribute (called CURYEAR). Give it a value of "Last Year" (literally, enter Last Year as text)

Then put a DateFormatter transformer in the workspace. Set it up to format CURYEAR. The source format is "Automatic Detection" and the destination format is "%Y"

That will return the 4-digit format for Last Year (eg 2015). Here's a screenshot (I used myDate instead of CURYEAR, but it's the same thing)

[image]

There I ran the workspace in 2016 and it told me the previous year was 2015

It works for any date and you can do similar relative-time things - like "3 Weeks Ago", "Next Tuesday" and "Yesterday". It's quite a neat capability.